# redirect to a subdomain in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, amazon-ec2, passenger

I just set up my rails 3 on Amazon EC2 with apache2 and passenger.

Everything is working great but when I created my first project inside
/var/www/html/ror/public/ the project does not show up. I tried mydomain.com/example which is the name of my project and it gives me an index of my rails project that I generated earlier. When I say index I mean a list of all the folders without rendering any html from the views. I guess my question is: how do I redirect the user to mydomain.com/example/app/views/example/index.html.erb

I tried playing around with httpd.conf and  but nothing seems to work out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing problems in deploying the site. Follow this -

1. Create a virtual host

   `$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/app-name`
2. Change the contents of the virtual host to

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>  
       ServerName  A.B.C.D  
       ServerAlias subdomain.abc.com  
       DocumentRoot /var/www/app-name/current/public
       RackEnv production
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Enable the new site

   `$ sudo a2ensite demo-app`
4. Restart Apache

   `$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Make sure you mention the correct document root.

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/app-name/current/public
```

More details - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Cw-oiE4AYrnbo_b7o593npTPaW8hRhRZERJ_ZETdrB8/edit?hl=en

Comment: thanks for the feedback im gona redo the whole thing now and I will let you know. Thanks for your time\

Comment: Fixed, my app was running on dev mode instead of production. classic mistake but still... Thanks for the help ppl

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `RailsBaseURI /ror/public` to your apache config.

Or, symlink:

```
mkdir /var/rails
mv /var/www/html/ror /var/rails
cd /var/www/html
ln -s /var/www/html/ror/public ror
```

(shouldn't put Rails app sources in your apache document tree)

and then `RailsBaseURI /ror`

Your app will be at example.com/ror

Comment: Since Im new in all these can you please be more specific as far as RailsBaseURI /ror where does it go exactly inside httpd.conf?

Comment: Anywhere, but I usually create a separate file -- you can put it in /etc/apache2/conf.d/rails.conf (create it if it doesn't exist).